# How to use Appium to test react native ios app

Tags: javascript, webdriver, ios-ui-automation, testcase, appium-ios

I have installed **Appium** using Node and I'm new to **Appium**. I have created react-native project. I want to test the iOS app using javascript. I'm able to start appium server using appium command. I tried to run test case using node `<filename.js>` but faced error like failed to install app I have some questions:

- how to create app?
- how start Appium server for simulator and real device.
- how to connect the appium server?
- to test in simulator(iPhone 7s), should I build release app or debug app?
- in which should I keep that app?
- where to write the device capabilities?
- what can be a basic test case in java scrips?

Basically I want to know both:

- steps to test in iOS simulator
- steps to test in real iOS device

in client side I want to write test cases in javascript.